# How to escape @ in password when doing ssh to remote server?

Tags: ssh, cmd, ip-address

I want to do ssh to remote server. So the command is

```
ssh username:password@ipaddress
```

But if my password contains @ then this command creates a problem. Obviously I can enter password in next step when prompt comes but I want to do in single step as displayed above. How can I escape the @ character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the url encoded version of @ sign: %40

Comment: Without wishing it to sound rude, I would appreciate it if you were to follow this answer up to clarify which `@` is to be URL encoded. The one in the password or the one preceding the ipaddress. As it stands there's room manoeuvre, hence my request.

Comment: The commonly used `ssh` utility doesn't accept URLs on the command line, and it doesn't accept a password on the command line, url-encoded or not. If the OP is able to specify a password the way he indicated, it's only because there's something unusual about the `ssh` program or the ssh server.

Comment: @Compo, it was the one for password. It accepts the url but again asks for password as a prompt.

Comment: Future users, are not to be expected to read through the comments. I know the answer, Raghav Gupta, what I want is that @commonsense, improves this answer in order that it is less unclear.